# Android resource linking failed Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am running into this weird issue where I am getting this error.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     C:\Users\live\project_backup\build\file_picker\intermediates\library_manifest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:9:5-15:15: AAPT: error: unexpected element <queries> found in <manifest>.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 15s
```

Weird thing is this happens after I upgrade `file_picker` package and persists even if I downgrade in pubspec.yaml again. But when I try run the project from the backup and replace lib folder with the one where this error occurred, it works perfectly. When this error occurs, plugin downgrade, flutter clean doesn't work. Why is this issue happening? When I click on the error link I am redirected to file_picker->intermediate->library_manifest->debug->Android Manifest.xml and the code there looks as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mr.flutter.plugin.filepicker" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />

            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
```

Any suggestions on what is wrong and how to fix this?

Comment: I am also getting this same error, stuck on this for 3 days

Comment: I haven't figure out exactly what causes this yet. I am just rolling back to previous backup and working without touching pubspec.yaml file right now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just found out the solution, queries is a new manifest element and require to use a new gralde android plugin.

so change to this version in build.gradle, this worked for me

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
```

Also change gradle-wrapper version to 6.5 as it is required by 4.1.0 plugin

EDIT:

use this if and only if app does not work in release mode, otherwise use above method.

use file_picker version `file_picker: 2.0.7` remember without ^ symbol. use android gradle plugin 3.5 only and don't migrate to 4.1.0.

Comment: Although it works, app gets stuck on splash screen when release apk is built. Everything works fine on debug and profile mode though :(

Comment: It works when rolled back. But still, a lot of bad experience with flutter this past month. Dart analyzer has been crashing so frequently that I don't even know hot reload exists or not anymore.

Comment: same here bruh, took so much time to fix this, with 3.5 file_picker was not working, i switched to 4.1 then firebase_core was not working, then it started working in debug but couldn't make it work in release. A lot of pain in this last week with flutter.

Comment: Still didnt fix my issue