# I create new app in flutter with flutter create AppName in vs code terminal it worked but when i try flutter run it shows this error message

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

[image]

[image]

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> Android resource linking failed
> AAPT: error: failed writing to 'C:\Users\Mii_Ranna\Desktop\vs test\projectname\build\app\intermedias invalid. (13).

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log o
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3m 1s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                       190.1s
The build failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Je
Building plugin integration_test...
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'... Done                    9.2s
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':compileReleaseAidl'.

> SDK location not found. Define location with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable or by setting ty setting tpath in your project's local properties file at 'C:\src\flutter\packages\integration_test\anhe sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at 'C:\src\flutter\packages\integrat           hion_test\an
> droid\local.properties'.

- Try:                                                                                                 o
  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':compileReleaseAidl'.

> SDK location not found. Define location with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable or b
> y setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at 'C:\src\flutter\packag
> es\integration_test\android\local.properties'.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to ge
  t more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s

Exception: The plugin integration_test could not be built due to the issue above.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log o
  utput. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s

Exception: The plugin integration_test could not be built due to the issue above.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android resource linking failed Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64548677/android-resource-linking-failed-flutter)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have Androidx enabled.

```
  android.useAndroidX=true
```

Make sure the classpath is set properly.

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
```