# Android resource linking failed for Flutter App

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, manifest, androidx

Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> Android resource linking failed
> build/app/intermediates/packaged_manifests/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:88: AAPT: error: resource attr/? (aka com.app.im:attr/?) not found.

([Android resource linking failed Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64548677/android-resource-linking-failed-flutter))
This answer which is mentioned the gradle need to be upgraded to 4.1.0
My current build gradle is 4.1.0 and gradle version is 6.7 but still could not solve it.

Android module of project run successfully but Flutter project failed to run.
Any solution can solve this?